# Creating standard users as a sysadmin in CKAN

Tags: ckan

Creating a standard user from the command line in CKAN.

Hi All,

We'd like to block self registration on our CKAN build, so ckan.auth.create_user_via_api and ckan.auth.create_user_via_web have been great.

However, we still need a way of making standard user accounts.
The CKAN documentation provides a way of creating a sysadmin user using a paster command (doc here: https://docs.ckan.org/en/ckan-2.7.3/maintaining/getting-started.html#create-admin-user)

Is there a way to create a standard user using a paster command?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a [CLI](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/maintaining/paster.html#user-create-and-manage-users) command to create standard user

`paster user add standard_user name=StandardUser email=standard_user@email.com password=password password1=password password2=password -c /path/to/production.ini`

Comment: Thanks.
The paster command I got to work was as follows:  
  `paster user add standard_user email=standard_user@email.com name=standard -c /path/to/production.ini`

Comment: great, ive missed the ini file in the example, thanks!

Comment: have you tried logging in as a sysadmin user then navigating to `<https://your-domain.com>/user/register`?  I'm pretty sure the user registration form will still work for sysadmins once you're logged in, even with the setting deactivated.  You can register new users this way instead of from the console.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see this come through.
Yes, using the "/user/register" URL works as well. Thanks!